# Check if columns in df contains specific set and assign value if true

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a problem with dataframe in python. My df looks like this:

```
type      object    name1   name2   name3   name4   name5   name6
PL          Y        NAM1   NAM2    NAM3    None    None    None
PL          Z        NamY   NAMZ    NAMI    MAMJ    NAMY    NamT
PL          Z        NamW   NAMG    NAMO    MAMR    NAMV    NamL
```

and set like this:

```
{'NAM1', 'MAMJ', .. }
```

I need to check if in columns name1 .. name6 is value from second set, if yes, that value must be assigned into new column.

I am able to do that with numpy but in many lines:

```
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name1'].isin(set1), df['name1'], '')
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name2'].isin(set1), df['name2'], df['matched'])
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name3'].isin(set1), df['name3'], df['matched'])
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name4'].isin(set1), df['name4'], df['matched'])
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name5'].isin(set1), df['name5'], df['matched'])
df['matched'] = np.where(df['name6'].isin(set1), df['name6'], df['matched'])
```

How can I do that in one line? Thank you for any hint!

Comment: for row 2 must be MAMJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `stack` to do this in two steps and apply a `groupby` and get the max index position value:

```
myset = {'NAM1', 'MAMJ'}

s = df.filter(like='name').stack()
s1 = s[s.isin(myset)].groupby(level=[0]).last()

print(s1)
0    NAM1
1    MAMJ
dtype: object
```

Then map onto your dataframe:

```
df['matched'] = df.index.map(s1) # add .fillna('') if you want to replace blanks with whitespace.

print(df)
    
  type object name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 matched
0   PL      Y  NAM1  NAM2  NAM3  None  None  None    NAM1
1   PL      Z  NamY  NAMZ  NAM1  MAMJ  NAMY  NamT    MAMJ
2   PL      Z  NamW  NAMG  NAMO  MAMR  NAMV  NamL     NaN
```

Comment: It doesn't working if there is no assignment, column matched value is not empty in that case

Comment: @JJ36 please add a sample.

Comment: I've added the third row into df in my question - after running in s1 in third row I have NAMG but it isn't inside myset.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to replace and have all matched items in set1 you can use the following code:

```
df = df.assign(
    matched = lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: set(s).intersection(set1),axis=1)
)
```

Comment: with this I got an error TypeError: ("'set' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 13580')

Comment: I think you have used set as a variable name at some point in your code. Thats why its an object now.

Comment: I know but maybe before that. if you can reset your notebook and not used set anymore it would be fixed

Comment: Could you please check it again?

Comment: I've tried with simple set of data (3 rows) and seems to be ok but for my large amount I got that error.. Maybe something with data.. but numpy is working..

Comment: I pasted it in my first comment

Comment: Do you have empty cells?

Comment: Yes, that could happen